# php expiration date with if statement

Tags: php, datetime, date, time, if-statement

I am trying to match a string to the current date. In the if statement if the string is equal or less than the current date i want to echo still active but it it has passed the cstring return expired. with the following code it always returns expired and the time zone is phenix/arizona not los angeles how can i fix these two issues

```
$current_date = date('F j Y g:i A e', strtotime('now'));
$expiration_date = date('F j Y g:i A e', strtotime('March 16 2011 9:29 am pst'));
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

if ($expiration_date < $current_date) {
        echo 'Still Avtive';
}
else

if ($expiration_date == $current_date) {
        echo 'Still Avtive';
}

else {
        echo 'Time Expired';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I used the following code and it seems to work. Hope this helps!

```
    <?php 
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
    // Set your desired Expiration Date here, using correct lettercases
    $exp_date = "June 1 2011 9:29 AM PST"; 

    // Using Capital 'A' in date() need capital in $exp_date: 'AM'. 'a' means  lowercase 'am'
    $todays_date = date("F j Y g:i A e"); 

    $today = strtotime($todays_date); 

    $expiration_date = strtotime($exp_date); 
    if ($expiration_date > $today) { 

        echo 'Still Active';

    } else { 

        echo 'Time Expired';

    } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Change the timezone first, before anything else.
2. Compare the values from strtotime instead of the date strings. strtotime returns an integer while date returns a formatted string.